# Summarize and aggregation of DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLIENT" : ["1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1"], 
                   "PRODUCT_ID" : [111, 112, 444, 555, 89, 765],
                   "AGREEMENT_ID" : [1443, 1443, 155, 888, 1443, 14543]})
```

And I need to create new DF and calculate average, median and max of products (PRODUCT_ID) per agreement (AGREEMENT_ID) for each client (CLIENT). I need results like below:

AVG = 1,666 because of 5 / 3

MED = 2 because of CLIENT 1 has 3 products on 1443 agreement 1 product on 888 agreement and 1 product on 14543 agreement so median = 2 ???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(['CLIENT', 'AGREEMENT_ID'])['PRODUCT_ID'].count().reset_index(name='product_count')
df_groupby = df_groupby.groupby(['CLIENT'])['product_count'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'max']).reset_index()
df_groupby

CLIENT  mean    median  max
1   1.666667    1   3
2   1.000000    1   1
```

**Median will be 1 and not 2 (explained below)**

If you groupby client and agreement id, the values of product_counts for client 1 are 1,3,1 (not 1,3 as mentioned in your example) and the median of these values (1,3,1) is 1 not 2.

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(['CLIENT', 'AGREEMENT_ID'])['PRODUCT_ID'].count().reset_index(name='product_count')
df_groupby

CLIENT  AGREEMENT_ID    product_count
1       888             1
1       1443            3
1       14543           1
2       155             1
```